# How can I build some chart with Chart.js and ng2-charts using an array of revenus & budgets per month date as Data source?

Tags: arrays, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I want to build some charts using Chart.js and ng2-charts. I have an array of data (week). I would like to know how to build an array of revenu-values and budget-values according to each date. These values will be shown on the Y-axis of the graph and the X-axis contains the labels ( [01, 02, 03, 04, 05, ..., 31] ) which are the month dates :

```js
week = [
         {
            date = "2019-03-01",
            revenu = 1000,
            budget = 800
         },
         {
            date = "2019-03-02",
            revenu = 1000,
            budget = 800
         },
         {
            date = "2019-03-03",
            revenu = 1000,
            budget = 800
         },
         {
            date = "2019-03-04",
            revenu = 1000,
            budget = 800
         },
         ...
       ];
       

public monthChartLabels= [01, 02, 03, 04, 05, ..., 31];
public monthChartData = [
  {
    data: [ ? ] // Array of revenu-values according to each date
  },
  {
    data: [ ? ] // Array of budget-values according to each date
  }  
];
```

```html
<canvas
        baseChart
        [chartType]=" 'line' "
        [datasets]="monthChartData"
        [labels]="monthChartLabels"
        [options]="monthLabels"
        [legend]="true"
        (chartHover)="onChartHover($event)">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shalom Eli, you should `map` your original data to the chart's `data` arrays: `week.map(e => e.revenu)` for the `revenu` dataset, and `week.map(e => e.budges)` for the `budget` dataset.

**Update**

Based on your comment, you want to convert your `week` array to a map keyed by the day of the month of each record:

```js
week.reduce((acc,v)=> ({
  ...acc,
  [new Date(v.date).getDate()]: v
}), {})
```

And then use your labels array to fetch each value from this map:

```js
revenuData = labels.map(r => this.weekMap[+r] && this.weekMap[+r].revenu);
budgetData = labels.map(r => this.weekMap[+r] && this.weekMap[+r].budget);
```

See this updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-3dfmxn

[image]

Comment: Shalom Aviad, your answer helped alot ! But my Week-Array is like following: 
week = [{
            date = "2019-03-05",
            revenu = 1000,
            budget = 800
         },
         {
            date = "2019-03-03",
            revenu = 1500,
            budget = 900
         },
       ...]; 
And I would like to know how the data[] for revenu & budget for each date will be constructed considering that, it shouldn't always start with the 1st. (ex. here start with 5th.) => Values for 1st. 2nd, 3th and 4th and all missing should be 0 for revenu and budget.

Comment: Thank you, your comments helped me alot! My week array is beind imported everyday, the sample week-array that I wrote here is very simple but the real one is something like : week = [{date: 2019-01-01, revenu = 1000, budget = 700}, { date: 2019-01-02, revenu = 1200, budget = 750} // JAN, { date: 2019-02-01, revenu = 1300, budget = 780}, {date: 2019-02-02, revenu = 1000, budget = 700} // FEB,  { date: 2019-03-01, revenu = 1500, budget = 790}, { date: 2019-03-02, revenu = 1800, budget = 300} // MARS, ...]- How can I convert this array as a date-keyed map ? Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want your x axis to look like?

Comment: My x axis looks like yours here: 1,2,.., 31. My problem is, I just noticed, that after mapping my week-array, which hassome days like "2019-02-01" and "2019-03-01", the map object was not correct.

Comment: The map takes the day part of the date. So if your range spans multiple months you need to somehow differentiate between different months.